# function Breaks when prototyped values in an associated function are missing

Tags: javascript

How do check to see if donald duck has a name in 'function inTheForest(object)' and if  it doesn't display an alert('no name found')  then move on to display the alerts for john person?

```
function Duck() {}

Duck.prototype.quack = function() {alert('Quaaaaaack!');};
Duck.prototype.feathers = function() {alert('The duck has white and gray    feathers.');};
//Duck.prototype.name = function() {alert('Donald Duck');};

function Person() {}

Person.prototype.quack = function() {alert('The person imitates a duck.');};
Person.prototype.feathers = function() {alert('The person takes a feather    from the ground and shows it.');};
Person.prototype.name = function() {alert('Rick James');};

function inTheForest(object) {
  object.quack();
  object.feathers();
  object.name(); 
}

function game() {
  var donald = new Duck();
  var john = new Person();
  inTheForest(donald);
  inTheForest(john);
}

game();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check by **[`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof)**

Like this

```
if(typeof object.name === "undefined"){
  console.log("no name found")
}
```

Comment: function inTheForest(object) {
  object.quack();
  object.feathers();
  if(typeof object.name === "undefined"){
  alert("no name found")
}else{
  object.name(); }
}   works

Comment: @D.C.Kensinger if it helps you then don't forget to mark this answer as accpted :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
function inTheForest(object) {
  object.quack();
  object.feathers();
  if(typeof object.name==='function'){
       object.name(); 
  }else{
      alert('no name found');
  }
}
```

In fact, you should always check if the property is a function before invoking it(if you are uncertain whether the prop exists). So you might want to use it for `quack` and `feathers` as well.

Comment: is there any advantage to checking function vs. undefined?

Comment: Yeah, if name was something other than function, name() would return a TypeError: name is not a function().

Answer (score 0):

a simple if statement if the `object.name` is exist

`object.name()? object.name(): alert("no name found");`

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do the following:

```
if (object.quack) object.quack();
if (object.feathers) object.feathers();
if (object.name) object.name();
```

You may also want to introduce `else` statement:

```
if (object.quack) 
    object.quack() 
else 
    console.log('Warning! Every object should be able to quack. Not found for ' + object);

if (object.feathers) object.feathers();
if (object.name) object.name();
```

This works because non-existent function is evaluated to **`undefined`**, which is **[falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy)**, and existent function is **[truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy)**.